# I just bought a Giant TCX SLR 2, but I still have money to spend. Which parts should I upgrade?

Tags: parts, upgrades, beginner, giant

I am new to bicycling. I bought this bike because it had good reviews and ratings and it fits the area where I am living. I am not intending to use this in a cyclocross race, but maybe in the future. I still have money to spend, **so which parts of the bike should I upgrade for the bike to function even better?**

Comment: What do you not own currently?  Given its a new bike, theres almost zero reason to change any part on it.  Get some miles out of the bike as-is then decide what parts don't suit you.

Comment: Buy a helmet, gloves, padded shorts, and a bright vest for yourself.  Bottle cages and bottles.  On-bike toolkit, spare tubes, pump, tyre levers, and somethign to carry them on the bike.  Lights, front and rear, two of each.  And stick any excess money in the bank for now.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Maybe I shouldn't worry about upgrading or changing the parts yet. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Criggie why pack into a comment if it could as well be a good answer?

Comment: @gschenk commenting cos it doesn't answer the question, which was specific to upgrading the bike's parts.

Comment: @Criggie "Don't do X, do Y instead" is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: Get Di2 if you can afford it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good investment for someone new to cycling who starts with such a sporty bike is to get a good bike fit. Based on the findings of the fit a part that maybe has to be replaced, is the stem. As these come at different lengths but are not adjustable.

You need to get pedals as well. You may choose between flat pedals, clip-less road pedals and clip-less mountain bike pedals. Each have their advantages as well as disadvantages on a cyclo-cross bike. For the clip-less pedals compatible shoes are needed.

Criggie mentioned in a comment useful tools and accessories that you might need depending on your intended use.

But first of all, get accustomed to the bike and find out what you like to use it for, as this changes everything.

For instance, if you use it to practice CX on a lawn, five minutes walk from your home, you will not need spare tubes and tools on your bike. Conversely, if you ride long remote gravel roads, a days march from the next settlement, you will need to be very well equipped for all kinds of field repairs. In addition, each use case requires a distinctly different bike fit.

Answer (score 4):

The answers are mostly opinion based but here goes ...

I'd leave the bike alone to start with. After you get an decent amount of miles on it a you may find you want a different length stem, different handlebar or seat etc.

To optimize your riding experience I'd invest in good, well fitting shoes and pedals, good clothing, helmet, water bottles, a multitool for on-trail adjustments. Some basic bike cleaning tools and supplies. Lights add some safety and extend riding into twilight and darkness hours.

If you *really, really* want to upgrade the bike itself, the best bet would be to return it and buy the next model up in the range (TCX Advanced Pro).

Answer (score 2):

After the fit, accessories and contact points, I think that wheels are the most important piece of hardware. Unfortunately it's usually the most expensive upgrade save a new group set.

Im going to disclude saddle and pedals because they're givens and they need to be comfortable so that expense is unavoidable and not necessarily and upgrade.

Good wheels are usually a nice upgrade, can last many years, can often be transferred from bike to bike and make a noticeable difference in ride.

Then I'd say good rubber to put on those wheels is money well spent. And maybe a good pair of fenders depending your local climate.